# GUI hangman game- how can I get these different parts to work together?

Tags: java, swing, class

I have (almost) working pieces of the game, but they don't work together. I am a complete beginner so I don't know how to work out where the problem is.
I have 3 classes:

- GameControls has the main functionality of the game in it.
- Hangman sets up a JFrame, calls the drawHangman method and contains the main method
- drawHangman has the instructions for drawing the hangman graphic

  I suspect this might not be the best way to do this so if the classes make no sense please let me know (and tell me why!).

## Problem

1. GameControls runs fine on its own. The user can select letters to guess, the display works, and the livesRemaining count goes down if the guess is wrong.
   BUT
   if I run from the hangman main method, the windows appear and the controls don't work anymore.
2. Even though the livesRemaining count decreases, I don't know how to make the drawHangman part use that variable and implement the switch statement to draw the hangman.

### My ideas

- It seems to me that the way the classes/methods are written/designed might be causing issues (but I don't know how to diagnose and fix this. I have tried!)
- I thought that the reason for problem 1 could be that when both windows open the program doesn't know where actions are coming from anymore and/or I need to add more ActionListener stuff.

  As I'm so new to programming it is taking me ages to look and this and try out different things, I would really like some pointers. My code is below.

#### Hangman class

```
    public class Hangman extends JFrame
    {
        public Hangman()
    {
        super("You have nine lives...");
        setSize(600,600);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        drawHangman draw = new drawHangman();
        add(draw);
        setVisible(true);
        }
    
        public static void main(String[] args)
        {
            GameControls play = new GameControls();
            Hangman game = new Hangman();
        
        }
        }
    }
```

#### GameControls class

```
    import java.awt.event.*;
    import javax.swing.*;
    import java.awt.*;

    public class GameControls extends JFrame implements ActionListener
    {

        String secretWord = "elephant"; //I'm assuming I will call a method that generates the  secretWord
        String clueGiven = "animal";
        int letterN = 0;
        int secretWordLength = secretWord.length();
        int livesRemaining = 10;
        boolean[] alreadyGuessed = new boolean[26];
    
        JLabel secretWordLabel = new JLabel("Word to guess: ", SwingConstants.RIGHT);
        JTextField displaySecretWord = new JTextField(secretWordLength);
        JLabel clueLabel = new JLabel("Clue: ", SwingConstants.RIGHT);
        JTextField clue = new JTextField(clueGiven, 15);
        JLabel guessLabel = new JLabel("Choose a letter: ", SwingConstants.RIGHT); 
        String[] letters = {"a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h","i","j","k","l","m","n","o","p","q","r","s","t","u","v","w","x","y","z"};
        JComboBox selectGuess = new JComboBox(letters);
        JButton submit = new JButton("Submit");
        JTextField displayGuessedLetters = new JTextField(15);
    
        public GameControls()
        {
            super("Hangman Game");
            setSize(340,170);
            setBounds(600,0,340,170);
            setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            setLookAndFeel();
         
            selectGuess.addActionListener(this); 
            submit.addActionListener(this);
            displaySecretWord.setEditable(false);
            clue.setEditable(false);
            displayGuessedLetters.setEditable(false);
        
            //show _ for all the letters of the secretWord
            for (letterN=0; letterN < secretWordLength; letterN++)
            {
                String displayedSoFar = displaySecretWord.getText();
                displaySecretWord.setText(displayedSoFar + " " + "_");
            }
        
            JPanel pane = new JPanel();
            GridLayout display = new GridLayout(4,2);
            pane.setLayout(display);
            pane.add(secretWordLabel);
            pane.add(displaySecretWord);
            pane.add(clueLabel);
            pane.add(clue);
            pane.add(guessLabel);
            pane.add(selectGuess);
            pane.add(displayGuessedLetters);
            pane.add(submit);
            add(pane);
            setVisible(true);
        
        }
    

        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event)
        {
            /*this works just fine when I run just this part of the program
            **but if I run it from the hangman main method it doesn't work.
            **I think it might be because then it has an extra window
            **so it doesn't know where the action is coming from for these bits here
            */
            Object source = event.getSource();
        
            boolean guessInWord;
            String prevGuesses = displayGuessedLetters.getText();
            char hideLetter = '_';
            int guessInt = selectGuess.getSelectedIndex();
            String guessChar = (String)selectGuess.getItemAt(guessInt);
        
            if (source == submit)
            {
                //store word as alreadyGuessed              
                alreadyGuessed[guessInt]=true;
                //check if it's in the word
                guessInWord = (secretWord.indexOf(guessChar)) != -1;
                boolean wordComplete = false;
            
                if (guessInWord == true)
                {
                    //print out the secretWord with the guessed letters showing
                    displaySecretWord.setText(" ");
                    for (letterN=0; letterN < secretWordLength; letterN++)
                    {
                    
                        String displayedSoFar = displaySecretWord.getText();
                        char letterToCheck = secretWord.charAt(letterN);
                        int letterToCheckIndex = (int)(letterToCheck)- 97;
                    
                        if (alreadyGuessed[letterToCheckIndex]==true)
                        {
                            displaySecretWord.getText();
                            displaySecretWord.setText(displayedSoFar + " " + letterToCheck);
                        }
                        else if (alreadyGuessed[letterToCheckIndex]==false)
                        {
                            displaySecretWord.getText();    
                            displaySecretWord.setText(displayedSoFar + " " + hideLetter);
                        }
                    }
                //check if the word is complete or not
                String displayedSoFar = displaySecretWord.getText();
                wordComplete = displayedSoFar.indexOf("_")== -1;
                if (wordComplete == true)
                {
                    //this bit opens but I haven't finished it yet
                    youWinPopup win = new youWinPopup();
                }
                }
            
                else if (guessInWord == false)
                {
                    //I can't figure out how to link this to my hangman drawing part!
                    livesRemaining --;
                    System.out.println(livesRemaining);
                    displayGuessedLetters.setText(prevGuesses + " " + guessChar);
                }
            } 
        }
    
        private void setLookAndFeel()
        {
            try
            {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel("com.sun.java.swing.plaf.nimbus.NimbusLookAndFeel");
                SwingUtilities.updateComponentTreeUI(this);
            }
            catch (Exception exc)
            {
                System.out.println("Couldn't use the system " + "look and feel: " + exc);
            }
        }

        /*public static void main (String[] args)
        {
            GameControls play = new GameControls(); //runs fine from here, without the hangman part
        }*/
    }
```

#### drawHangman class

```
        import java.awt.*;
        import java.awt.geom.*;
        import javax.swing.*;

        public class drawHangman extends JPanel 
        {
        /**
         * 
         */
        private static final long serialVersionUID = -3924721752542320241L;

        public void paintComponent (Graphics comp)
        {
            Graphics2D comp2D = (Graphics2D) comp;
            comp2D.setColor(Color.white);
            comp2D.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING,RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
            Rectangle2D.Float background = new Rectangle2D.Float(0F,0F,400,600/*(float)getSize().width,(float)getSize().height*/);
                comp2D.fill(background);
        
            //setting for colour etc
            comp2D.setColor(Color.black);
            BasicStroke pen = new BasicStroke(2.0f,BasicStroke.CAP_BUTT, BasicStroke.JOIN_ROUND);
            comp2D.setStroke(pen);      
        
            int livesRemaining = 10;
            switch (livesRemaining)
            {
            case '9':
                Line2D.Float gallowsBase = new Line2D.Float(50F,500F,500F,500F);
                comp2D.draw(gallowsBase); 
                break;
            case '8':   
                Line2D.Float gallowsVertical = new Line2D.Float(150F,500F,150F,100F);
                comp2D.draw(gallowsVertical);
                break;
            case '7':
                Line2D.Float gallowsTop = new Line2D.Float(150F,100F,400F,100F);
                comp2D.draw(gallowsTop);
                break;
            case '6':
                Line2D.Float rope = new Line2D.Float(400F,100F,400F,150F);
                comp2D.draw(rope);
                break;
            case '5':
                Ellipse2D.Float head = new Ellipse2D.Float(362F,150F,76F,76F);
                comp2D.draw(head); 
                break;
            case '4':
                Line2D.Float body = new Line2D.Float(400F,226F,400F,325F);
                comp2D.draw(body);
                break;
            case '3':
                Line2D.Float arm1 = new Line2D.Float(400F,226F,300F,275F);
                comp2D.draw(arm1);
                break;
            case '2':
                    Line2D.Float arm2 = new Line2D.Float(400F,226F,500F,275F);
                comp2D.draw(arm2);
                break;
            case '1':
                Line2D.Float leg1 = new Line2D.Float(400F,325F,300F,400F);
                comp2D.draw(leg1);
                break;
            case '0':
                Line2D.Float leg2 = new Line2D.Float(400F,325F,500F,400F);
                comp2D.draw(leg2);
                /*youLosePopup lose = new youLosePopup();*/
            }    
        }
        /*public static void main (String[] args)
        {
            drawHangman draw = new drawHangman(); 
        }*/
    }
```

Comment: miss there `super.paintComponent` as 1st code line in `public void paintComponent (Graphics comp`), maybe `dispose()` as last code line in the same code block (really not important in comparing with `super.paintComponent`)

Comment: `UIManager.setLookAndFeel(.....` should be 1st code line in `public static void main(String[] args)`

Answer (score 6):

- `livesRemaining` is an integer.
- When you put it in a `switch` statement, your cases should be integers not characters.

  ```
  case 6:
  ```

  instead of

  ```
  case '6':
  ```

Good luck.